# SQL Server - Creating Grouped Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am needing to create some columns where I sum values to create a "grouped" value data set. Here is the data I have and below is what I need as an output. Any help is much appreciated!

**Current Data Set**

```
Reference ID    Numerator   Denominator Cycle Value Action Plan
CLM-12-FLC-MMA  90  100 90% A
CLM-12-FLC-LTC  80  100 80% B
CLM-13-FLC-MMA  120 200 60% A
CLM-13-FLC-LTC  200 200 100%    B
CLM-16-FLC-MMA  25  50  50% A
CLM-16-FLC-LTC  50  50  100%    B
```

**Output Needed**

```
**Grouped Ref ID**  Reference ID    Numerator   Denominator Cycle Value **Grouped Numerator Grouped Denominator Grouped Cycle Value**   Action Plan
CLM-12-FLC  CLM-12-FLC-MMA  90  100 90% 170 200 85% A
CLM-12-FLC  CLM-12-FLC-LTC  80  100 80% 170 200 85% B
CLM-13-FLC  CLM-13-FLC-MMA  120 200 60% 320 400 80% A
CLM-13-FLC  CLM-13-FLC-LTC  200 200 100%    320 400 80% B
CLM-16-FLC  CLM-16-FLC-MMA  25  50  50% 75  100 75% A
CLM-16-FLC  CLM-16-FLC-LTC  50  50  100%    75  100 75% B
```

New Code Update:

```
select 
    GroupedRefID = x.NewRefID
    ,ss.[Reference ID]
    , s.[Numerator Value]
    , s.[Denominator Value]
    , convert(varchar(10), s.[Cycle Value]) + '%'
    , GroupedNumerator = x.NumeratorTotal
    , GroupedDenominator = x.DenominatorTotal
    , GroupedCycleValue = convert(varchar(10), convert(int, 100 * (x.NumeratorTotal / (x.DenominatorTotal * 1.0) /*need to multiple by 1.0 so this becomes a decimal*/))) + '%'
    , s.[Action Plan to be Compliant]
from MEACycleSnapShot s
    left join MEACONFIGSnapshot ss
    on s.Configuration = ss.[Configuration Number]

where convert(date,s.CreatedOn) = 
(select max(convert(date,CreatedOn)) from s)
and convert(date,ss.CreatedOn) = 
(select max(convert(date,CreatedOn)) from ss) 
and convert(date,s.EndofReportingPeriod) > '02/01/2016'
and ss.[MEA Set] in ('Medicaid - Metrics', 'Medicare - Metrics')
and ss.[Configuration Status] in ('Active','Gap')
and ss.[Reference ID] IN ('CLM-12-FLC-LTC','CLM-12-FLC-MMA','CLM-13-FLC-LTC','CLM-13-FLC-MMA','CLM-16-FLC-LTC','CLM-16-FLC-MMA','CLM-17-FLC-LTC','CLM-17-FLC-MMA') 

cross apply

(select NewRefID = left([Reference ID], LEN([Reference ID]) - charindex('-', reverse([Reference ID])))
    , NumeratorTotal = sum(cast([Numerator Value] as float))
    , DenominatorTotal = sum(cast([Denominator Value] as float))
 from MEACycleSnapShot
    left join MEACONFIGSnapshot
    on MEACycleSnapShot.Configuration = MEACONFIGSnapshot.[Configuration Number]
    where convert(date,MEACycleSnapShot.CreatedOn) = 
    (select max(convert(date,CreatedOn)) from MEACycleSnapShot)
    and convert(date,MEACONFIGSnapshot.CreatedOn) = 
    (select max(convert(date,CreatedOn)) from MEACONFIGSnapshot) 
    and convert(date,MEACycleSnapShot.EndofReportingPeriod) > '02/01/2016'
    and MEACONFIGSnapshot.[MEA Set] in ('Medicaid - Metrics', 'Medicare - Metrics')
    and MEACONFIGSnapshot.[Configuration Status] in ('Active','Gap')
    and [Reference ID] IN ('CLM-12-FLC-LTC','CLM-12-FLC-MMA','CLM-13-FLC-LTC','CLM-13-FLC-MMA','CLM-16-FLC-LTC','CLM-16-FLC-MMA','CLM-17-FLC-LTC','CLM-17-FLC-MMA')
    and left([Reference ID], LEN([Reference ID]) - charindex('-', reverse([Reference ID]))) = left([Reference ID], LEN([Reference ID]) - charindex('-', reverse([Reference ID])))
    group by left([Reference ID], LEN([Reference ID]) - charindex('-', reverse([Reference ID])))) x
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic here? The output values make no sense to me.

Comment: My apologies! So the first 2 rows are being grouped into a new Grouped Ref ID column as 'CLM-12-FLC', then the Grouped Numerator/Denominator columns need to sum the Numerators and Denominators from the first 2 rows, and then divide those sums to create the Grouped Cycle Value column. Similar logic for rows 3-4 and 5-6.

Comment: Huh? Something doesn't make sense there. I don't get it. It is really difficult to decipher what is what in your output because the column names have spaces in them and nothing is lined up cleanly.

Comment: You have the CROSS APPLY after your where clause. I think you probably want to pull most of your data into a cte so you don't have to query it more than once. Also, reading about CROSS APPLY so you understand what it is doing would be pertintent. Here are a couple great article on the topic. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-and-using-apply-part-1 and https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/understanding-and-using-apply-part-2

Comment: Also, I would avoid the float datatype as the result is not always accurate because float is an approximate datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the biggest reasons you are struggling here is because you seem to have violated 1NF by shoving multiple values into the ReferenceID column. This means you have to jump through a bunch of hurdles to unravel that. If I understand what you are looking for this should work.

Notice how I created some sample data in a consumable format? That is how you should present data in the future. It makes it so others can work on your problem easily. :D

```
declare @Something table
(
    ReferenceID varchar(25)
    , Numerator int
    , Denominator int
    , CycleValue int
    , ActionPlan char(1)
)

insert @Something values
('CLM-12-FLC-MMA', 90, 100, 90, 'A')
, ('CLM-12-FLC-LTC', 80, 100, 80, 'B')
, ('CLM-13-FLC-MMA', 120, 200, 60, 'A')
, ('CLM-13-FLC-LTC', 200, 200, 100, 'B')
, ('CLM-16-FLC-MMA', 25, 50, 50, 'A')
, ('CLM-16-FLC-LTC', 50, 50, 100, 'B')

select GroupedRefID = x.NewRefID
    , s.ReferenceID
    , s.Numerator
    , s.Denominator
    , convert(varchar(10), s.CycleValue) + '%'
    , GroupedNumerator = x.NumeratorTotal
    , GroupedDenominator = x.DenominatorTotal
    , GroupedCycleValue = convert(varchar(10), convert(int, 100 * (x.NumeratorTotal / (x.DenominatorTotal * 1.0) /*need to multiple by 1.0 so this becomes a decimal*/))) + '%'
    , s.ActionPlan
from @Something s
cross apply
(
    select NewRefID = left(s2.ReferenceID, LEN(s2.ReferenceID) - charindex('-', reverse(s2.ReferenceID)))
        , NumeratorTotal = sum(s2.Numerator)
        , DenominatorTotal = sum(s2.Denominator)
    from @Something s2
    where left(s2.ReferenceID, LEN(s2.ReferenceID) - charindex('-', reverse(s2.ReferenceID))) = left(s.ReferenceID, LEN(s.ReferenceID) - charindex('-', reverse(s.ReferenceID)))
    group by left(s2.ReferenceID, LEN(s2.ReferenceID) - charindex('-', reverse(s2.ReferenceID)))
) x
```

Comment: Hi Sean - thank you for your solution. I have tried to apply it to my scenario and provided the code I am using in the original post. I am getting 2 errors: 1. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'cross' & 2. Incorrect syntax near 'x'. Do you have any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? The code posted here works just fine. That indicate that either you are using sql server 2000 or older, or you didn't implement this correctly. Without knowledge of the version or the code you are trying there isn't much help I can offer.

Comment: I edited the original post above with the code I am using. I'm using 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to sum based on the first 10 characters of the reference.  Use window functions and `left()`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(numerator) over (partition by left(reference_id, 10)),
       sum(denominator) over (partition by left(reference_id, 10)),
       sum(cycle) over (partition by left(reference_id, 10)),
from t;
```